# sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice: how to iterate data from nested models? (Symfony 1.4)

Tags: symfony1, symfony-forms, symfony-1.4

I have the ConnectForm with nested fields from other model: Numbers.
I want to render this ConnectForm with all Numbers and everything works well when i just

```
    <?php echo $form['numbers_list'] ?>
```

But i need to print other Numberss' fields like: price, code etc.
How to print it?

The best way for me would something like this:

```
    <?php foreach($form['numbers_list'] as $num): ?>
        <span> echo $num->renderInput()</span>
        <span>echo $num->getPrice()</span>
        <span>echo $num->getCode()</span>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably are better off creating a custom sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatter class and then using that to output your form - you can output a whole form once you have created your new sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatter class by doing `<?php echo $form ?>` for example :

```
class sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatterCustom extends sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatter
{
  protected
    $rowFormat       = "<span class=\"my-label-class\">%label%</span>\n  <span>%error%%field%%help%%hidden_fields%</span>`n",
    $errorRowFormat  = "<span class=\"my-error-class\" colspan=\"2\">\n%errors%</span>\n",
    $helpFormat      = '<br />%help%',
    $decoratorFormat = "<div>\n  %content%</div>";
}
```

Then within the configure method of your form add the following that tells the form to use your custom decorator :

`$this->getWidgetSchema()->setFormFormatterName('custom');`

Comment: It works for entire form? I need just customize output for nested data in form. How to do that?

Comment: Just change the rowFormat to match the row format you need ... then you can just output the entire form

Comment: I'm sorry. I explained it bad i think, or i just don't understand you:
the problem when i output choices is that i get only it's id's, not other row from DB.

Comment: ahh ok - then you need to look at this page -> http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice and use the `method` parameter ....

Comment: Yes. But method parameter works only for value wich will be printed inside formatted html. I want to format that html by myself.

Comment: OK- in your action where you create the $form - also create $numlist / or something similar which is a list of the works / fields you want - then echo those onto the template ......